# CSS Issues with image and input field

Tags: css

I am having difficulties manipulating an input field, image and text all in the same line. I have set float to the image and text but it doesnt solve the issue. How can I make the image, text and input be all in one line for all browsers?

[image]

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-style: italic;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #898989;
    font-size: 140%;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin: 0px;

}



h2 {
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 105%;
    margin: 0px;

}

input, select {
    border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    color: #222;
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    font-family: trebuchet, 'trebuchet ms', 'tahoma', sans-serif;
}

input:focus, select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

.InputGroup {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
}

input.medium, select.medium{
    width:55%;
}

.youTubePng {

float:left; padding-right: 5px;


}

.youTubeLink {
padding-right:5px; float:left; padding-top: 3px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<form autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"  name="form">
                    <h1 style="padding-left:0;">Video(Optional)</h1>
                     <img src="images/YouTube.png" class="youTubePng" />
                     <h2 id="youTubeLink">Link:</h2>

                    <input id="ytinput" name="ytinput" type="text" class="field text medium" value="<? $url ?>" maxlength="255" tabindex="1"    />


       </form>
```

Comment: remove the `</html>` from your `<form>` !!!!!

Comment: Here is a demo before: (your code) http://jsbin.com/edafun/edit#javascript,html,live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: remove the `</html>` from your `<form>`.
Try to wrap the desired into a `<label>` !
Remove the `<h2>` and replace it with a `<span>`

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/upatob/2/edit)*

```
<label for="ytinput">
    <img src="images/YouTube.png" class="youTubePng" />
    <span id="youTubeLink">Link:</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

h2 is, by default, a block element. It's not going to share the line with anything. Unless you have a really good reason for it being in an h2, take the advice of the other chap and use a label instead.